# JavaScript library for creating canvas background transition effects

Tags: css, flash, html5-canvas

So I'm rewriting Flash games to HTML5 using JavaScript, CSS and HTML and it seems that in order to do simple stuff I need to take quite a big amount of time researching even for simple things, because I don't feel that doing everything from scratch is the best way.

So what I'm looking for is some kind of JS library to create different kinds of background transition effects, so it works like a slideshow. Let's say I have a game menu and then I want to smoothly switch to the actual game, like with ease-in effect and such quite similarly like MS PowerPoint does when going through the slides. All I can think of now is to code it from scratch with would take a lot more time for me since I didn't do a lot of stuff with the animations.

Also it's nearly impossible to find similar HTML5 games that I'm trying to rebuild so I can take an example of them and maybe see the code how it is done.

Any help what library should I try, or maybe other alternatives like using CSS3 or such would be nice, but as far as I know there's no a few lines of code solution, would be glad if someone could prove me wrong.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to see a real case: https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=html5+games